# Python Numpy ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 2, 2)

Tags: python, numpy

This is my numpy array:

```py
array([[['a','c'], [1,3]],

[['b','d'], [2, 4]]], dtype=object)
```

Expected dataframe:

| columns1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| ['a','c'] | [1, 3] |
| ['b','d'] | [2, 4] |

Getting this error

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 2, 2)
 with `pd.DataFrame((c), columns=['q','s'])
```

Comment: what don't you understand?  why it's a (2,2,2) array, or why pandas has problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you consider your numpy array as a 2 by 2 matrix with lists as their elements. But what actually happens is that these lists are casted into an additional dimensions.

I don't know if there is a more direct solution, but here is one way to trick numpy into the desired structure:

```
>>> c=numpy.array([[['a', 'c'], [1]], [['b', 'd'], [2,4]]])
>>> c
array([[list(['a', 'c']), list([1])],
       [list(['b', 'd']), list([2, 4])]], dtype=object)
>>> c[0,1].append(3)
>>> c
array([[list(['a', 'c']), list([1, 3])],
       [list(['b', 'd']), list([2, 4])]], dtype=object)
>>> pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['q','s'])
        q       s
0  [a, c]  [1, 3]
1  [b, d]  [2, 4]
```

In the first step, one of the inner lists has a different length, therefore numpy cannot broadcast this to an array with 3 dimensions and returns your desired 2 dimensional array with lists as its elements instead. Next I simply append the missing value.

An alternative could be to simply skip the numpy array and pass the list of lists of lists directly to pandas:

```
>>> c=[[['a', 'c'], [1, 3]], [['b', 'd'], [2,4]]]
>>> pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['q','s'])
        q       s
0  [a, c]  [1, 3]
1  [b, d]  [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**

```
import pandas as pd


a = pd.Series([['a','c'],[1,3]])
b = pd.Series([['b','d'],[2,4]])

df = pd.DataFrame([a,b])

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:** Nope you need those extra brackets, my bad. But if you do this, it works:

```
data = np.array([[['a,'c'], [1,3]],

[['b','d'], [2, 4]]], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
```

---

**Original:**

I think you might have one set of square brackets too many and thus, it sees three dimensions instead of the two you're seeking.

You can try:

```
np.array([['a,'c'], [1,3]],

[['b','d'], [2, 4]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it does not return my desired output.

Comment: Sorry, should have read more closely. I've updated with code that yields your desired output, but uses ```pd.Series```. Will that work for you?